# Rerouting of server from local to amazon?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, server

I'm setting up a new server on AWS, everything is working as expected. but I recently found out that in order to be elegible for business in my country I need to have the server be local. Is there a way I would reroute the server on request? like point to local IP, but all the rest api/admin panel would show/result AWS server?

This is a new problem for me, have not tried anything.

Comment: So you're asking how to run the server in a different country, but make it "look like" it is running in _your_ country? That won't be possible unless you have something in your country that can redirect the request.